# Find highest number using only operators, variables, input and typecasting

Tags: python, max

My homework is:

I need to write a code that will let the user enter 3 numbers(this
part is done.). Then my code should compare those numbers with each
other(I think I know this too). But the hardest part is: if the first
number is the greatest, then code should print *1st: true*, if the second one
is the greatest, it should print *2nd: true* and so on.

Also I can't use strings, if else and others the only thing I can use are
operators, variables, input and typecasting.

I came up with this idea:

```
first = int(input('Write first number: '))
second = int(input('Write second number: '))
third = int(input ('Write third number: '))

print (f'1st: {first > second and first> third}')
print (f'2nd: {second > first and second > third}')
print (f'3rd: { third > first and third > second}')
```

Comment: Should you be printing "1st: False" if the first number is not the smallest?

Comment: Using `max()` would give more readable code, but I understand you may not be allowed to use it. When you paste your code into a Python interpreter, what happens after you have downshifted all the incorrect initial capital letters (in `First`, `Print`, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a pretty specific and restrictive application. In your case, one could go with a ternary operator to eliminate the `if else` statement:

```py
(false_value, true_value)[conditional_expression]
```

In the example below, I am assuming you would want to output `False` in the case that the conditions are not met. If this is not the case, I would suggest leaving it a blank string, i.e `""`

```py
first = int(input('Write first number: '))
second = int(input('Write second number: '))
third = int(input('Write third number: '))

first_result = ("1st: False", "1st: True")[(first > second) and (first > third)]
second_result = ("2nd: False", "2nd: True")[(second > first) and (second > third)]
third_result = ("3rd: False", "3rd: True")[(third > first) and (third > second)]

print(first_result)
print(second_result)
print(third_result)
```

Comment: Your code looks useful actually. I had a discussion with my classmate about your code and they said this might work. Thank you so much

Comment: @Love You're most welcome. If you found this useful, please use this answer to mark your question as answered.

Comment: I'm new around here how do I do that

Comment: @Love You do that by clicking on the tick next to the answer you found most helpful. Additionally, if you wish, an upvote (clicking the upwards arrow) would also be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Love, I noticed that you used my answer which I gave a couple of months ago in your own answer. I'm glad to see that the information was helpful to you, but I kindly request that you credit me as the source by marking my answer as the accepted answer to your question. This will help other users who come across this thread know where the information came from. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use the code below:

```
first = int(input('Write first number: '))
second = int(input('Write second number: '))
third = int(input ('Write third number: '))
temp=first > second and first> third and print("1st:True")
temp=second > first and second > third and print("2st:True")
temp=third > first and third > second and print("3st:True")
```

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

```
first = int(input('Write first number: '))
second = int(input('Write second number: '))
third = int(input('Write third number: '))

first_result = ("1st: False", "1st: True")[(first > second) and (first > third)]
second_result = ("2nd: False", "2nd: True")[(second > first) and (second > third)]
third_result = ("3rd: False", "3rd: True")[(third > first) and (third > second)]

print(first_result)
print(second_result)
print(third_result)
```